# css вывести псевдо-элемент за пределы overflow hidden

Tags: css

Должен сделать стрелки как псевдо-элементы за пределами div, в котором поставлен `overflow: hidden;`. Как это можно сделать, то есть, что бы тот псевдо-элемент не был скрываем, а показывался?

```css
.d0 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 333px;
  height: 44px;
  background: olive;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.d0:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: all;
  content: ' ';
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<div class='d0'>+++</div>
```

Comment: за пределы overflow не возможно переделывайте

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть такой вариант, обернуть элемент другим.

Убрать у `.d0` — `position: absolute`.

И задать его только обертке и псевдоэлементу:

```css
.d0 {
  width: 333px;
  height: 44px;
  background: olive;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 333px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.d0:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: all;
  content: '';
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='d0'>+++</div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, спасибо, точно, что нужно убрать пзицию. Думаю, другой вариант - использовать grid для позиционирования, хоть и возможны проблемы совместимости старых браузеров в таком случае.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score -1):

```
.container {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните свой ответ. Дополнить его можно, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1006229/edit).